# Failed to run safari webdriver on mac OS

Tags: macos, selenium, safari, selenium-webdriver

I am running selenium tests on mac os, and I have no problem running the safari driver locally on the mac machine , but when trying to run the tests via TeamCity agent (same code as local), I keep getting the Error:

```
Aug 10, 2014 6:16:27 PM org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverServer start
[18:16:27][exec] INFO: Server started on port 10862
[18:16:27][exec] Aug 10, 2014 6:16:27 PM org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverCommandExecutor start
[18:16:27][exec] INFO: Launching Safari
[18:16:27][exec] Aug 10, 2014 6:16:27 PM org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverCommandExecutor start
[18:16:27][exec] INFO: Waiting for SafariDriver to connect
[18:17:12][exec] INFO: Stopping server
[18:17:12][exec] Aug 10, 2014 6:17:12 PM org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverServer stop
org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverCommandExecutor stop
[18:17:12][exec] INFO: Shutdown complete
[18:17:19][exec]  Original message: org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Failed to connect to SafariDriver after 45072 ms
[18:17:19][exec] Build info: version: '2.42.0', revision: '5e82430', time: '2014-05-22 20:18:07'
[18:17:19][exec] System info: host: 'eyals-Mac-mini.local', ip: '192.168.1.102', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.9.4', java.version: '1.8.0_11'
[18:17:19][exec] Driver info: driver.version: SafariDriver
```

Why is that happening?

This is my code for running the driver:

```
dc = DesiredCapabilities.safari();
SafariOptions safariOptions = new SafariOptions();
safariOptions.setUseCleanSession(true);
safariOptions.setDataDir(new File(System.getProperty("user.home") +"/Library/Safari"));
dc.setCapability(SafariOptions.CAPABILITY, safariOptions);
dc.setCapability(CapabilityType.UNEXPECTED_ALERT_BEHAVIOUR, UnexpectedAlertBehaviour.IGNORE);
dc.setPlatform(Platform.MAC);
driver = new SafariDriver(dc);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The only solution is to allot more memory to your mac machine or get a better mac with more Ram. I reinstalled my mac OS to deal with this issue.